# I18n - locale file - use ruby - use translation()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, translation

In a `I18n locale file` (eg el.yml):

- can I use `translation` method in order to use an already defined translation?
- can I use `ruby code` inside?

For example, in the `locale yml file`, in several places I want to use the word "`Invalid`". So one approach is to **translate the word "Invalid" each time**

Another approach is to `translate it once`, at the top, and then in each translation inside the locale yml which contains this word I could use something like `t(:invalid)`..

eg:

```
el:
  # global translations - in order to be used later in the file
  locked: 'kleidomeno'
  invalid: 'mi egiro'
  password: 'kodikos'

  devise:
    failure:
      invalid: "#{Invalid} %{authentication_keys} or #{password}."
      locked: "Your account is #{locked}."
      last_attempt: "You have one more attempt before your account is #{locked}."
      not_found_in_database: "#{invalid} %{authentication_keys} ή #{password}."
```

Comment: Why do you want to use Ruby in your I18n file? Can you please explain what you try to achieve?

Comment: Dear @spickemann,
I added the clarification to the question above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I use translation method in order to use an already defined translation?

Yes, that's what I18n translation comes for, e.g.

```
t 'something'
```

> can I use ruby code inside?

No, it's a .yml file, which does not accept Ruby or any other programming languages.

> Another approach is to translate it once

To translate once, you can write a new Rake task to generate the target yml for you.

Or maybe, wrap the official translation function with a new method, which can recognize your custom string syntax:

```
# custom translate
def ct(msg)
  msg.gsub(/#\{\s*([^\}]+)\s*\}/) {|_| t $1}
end
```

Call it like:

```
ct 'Your account is #{locked}.'
```

I think you'd better remove these failure strings out of your yml file if so.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply

For the first question I would like to clarify that I mean in the locale.yml file.

For example, in several places I want to use the word "Invalid". 
So one approach is to translate the word "Invalid" each time
Another approach is to translate it once, at the top, and then in each translation inside the locale yml  which contains this word I could use something like t(:invalid)...

Comment: @AndreasGortsilas What do you mean for **once** here? If you just want to configue your website for only one language, you can just use one . Once you have to support multiple languages at the same time, still, you have to decide the langue for each visitor. From your description, seems like you want to have all the worlds translated once a visitor came, and put them into a session global variable, which is somehow cumbersome in my option, because so many translations are wasted in this one session.

Comment: Dear @hxpax, I added a sample part of the locale.yml file
I hope that you understand now what I am asking...

Comment: Dear @hxpax,
Thank you very much for your kind time and effort

Comment: Dear @hxpax one more question,
If I follow the `ct method` approach, does it get called each time a translation is needed in the run-time?
or it is called somewhat different?
I wonder if this kind of approach has severe `performance issues`.
Is this the same approach that the original `t method` uses for handling the passing of variables to translations, like `authentication_keys` in my sample code?

Comment: @AndreasGortsilas Yeah it will be called every time a visitor comes unless you do another layer of cashing. From this perspective, use Rake to generate YAMLs may be better. For Rake tasks on Rails, check [This blog](https://medium.com/@balogic/creating-a-rake-task-and-importing-data-from-a-file-to-a-table-in-rails-5-c67ff1f69f42)